# sup of A Union B

Tags: analysis

Assumgin A,B, two set are upper-bounded.
I need to prove that A Union B is also upper bounded and the supremum is max(supA, supB).

This question can be explained intuitivly, but how do you prove it in a formal/mathemtical way?
Thanks!

Comment: How are you defining the "union" of two sequences?

Comment: sorry, I ment "set", not "sequnces"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

Step one is to show that the set $A\cup B$ is bounded above.  We know that $A$ is bounded above by $\sup A$, and that $B$ is bounded above by $\sup B$.  We also know that $\sup A\leq\max\{\sup A, \sup B\}$ and $\sup B\leq\max\{\sup A,\sup B\}$, by definition of the maximum.  How can you combine these to show that $\max\{\sup A,\sup B\}$ is an upper bound on $A\cup B$?

Step two: having shown that $\max\{\sup A,\sup B\}$ is an upper bound, you must show that it is the *least* upper bound.  So, suppose that you have an upper bound $M$ on $A\cup B$ which satisfies $M<\max\{\sup A,\sup B\}$. Why is this a contradiction if $M<\sup A$?  What about if $M<\sup B$?  Show these are both impossible, and you're done -- since being less than the maximum require that one or the other holds.

Comment: These hints helped me greatly with a homework problem. Thank  you very much!